# how to refer to a dependency PowerShell file when compiling to EXE using PowerGUI

Tags: powershell, dependencies, exe, powergui

I am trying to compile two separated Powershell files into a single .EXE using the solution [PowerGUI](http://software.dell.com/products/powergui-freeware/) .
It seems to support this feature as it even has a button called Dependencies for that purpose.
But I couldn't find any example of how to refer to a dependency file from any other PowerShell file included in the same .EXE

My main PS file only contains the following line:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit -file C:\PGM\usbControl.ps1"
```

I would like to know how to encode "C:\PGM\usbControl.ps1" as a relative path inside the .EXE package and point to the dependency included.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I didnt have to use any external IDE, standard powershell code did the trick. Embed code! :) the ScriptBlock was the key.

```
$sb = {

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA ''Win32_LogicalDisk'' AND TargetInstance.DriveType=2'

        Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier RemovableDiskDetection -Action {
            $class = $eventArgs.NewEvent.__CLASS
            $device = $eventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.DeviceID

            $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
            switch ($class)
            {
                __InstanceCreationEvent {
                    $path = $device + '\flag\'
                    Write-Host '*** Checking the existence of the file $path'
                    if (Test-Path -Path $path)
                    {
                        $wshell.Popup('Inserted, device id: $device WITH flag', 0, 'Done', 0x1)

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $wshell.Popup('Inserted, device id: $device WITHOUT flag', 0, 'Done', 0x1)
                    }
                }
                __InstanceDeletionEvent {
                    $wshell.Popup('Removed, device id: $device ', 0, 'Done', 0x1)
                }
           }
        }
}

start-process powershell.exe -argument "-noexit -nologo -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -command $sb"
```

After this nice workaround, I just used the [PS2EXE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PS2EXE-Convert-PowerShell-9e4e07f1) tool to compile it.

```
.\ps2exe.ps1  -noConsole -inputFile .\magic.ps1 -outPutFile magic.exe
```